# Asp.Net MVC 301 Redirects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-status-code-301

We used to use ISAPI Re-Write (Infact its still on our server) although it doesnt work with ASP.Net MVC (Somthing to do with 'euxd' get param).

We need a relaiable way to implement simple 301 redirects, when we change the site structure, upload a new site etc. Any suggestions?

Ok, it I wanted to redirect /SomeFolder/SomePage.HTML?Param1=X to /NewPage/X

How can we do that?

Comment: Are you wanting to redirect *non-MVC* page requests to an MVC controller action as in your example?

Comment: Correct, so OLD pages (Previous site written in PHP) to the new pages written in .Net MVC 3

Comment: What version of IIS are you going to be running on the new server?

Comment: @Charlino same server just a new website, its IIS7

Comment: If you are using IIS7, I would recommend using the official IIS7 URL Rewrite Module. See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using IIS7, I would recommend using the official [IIS7 URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).

- [Using the URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/)
- [Using URL Rewrite Module 2.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/664/using-url-rewrite-module-20/)

Comment: Just found this, perfect for what we need!!

Answer (score 37):

In MVC 3 there are three new redirect methods that can be used in controllers to redirect permanently (produce a 301); as opposed to the 302s (temporary redirect) produced by the MVC 2 redirects.

- RedirectPermanent
- RedirectToActionPermanent
- RedirectToRoutePermanent

> ```
> public ActionResult OldAction()
> {
>   return RedirectPermanent(urlname);
> }
> ```

There is a great tutorial in the [Controllers](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-mvc3) section of these walkthroughs on PluralSight.

Comment: You'll need a `return` in there too.

Comment: Hightechrider - added the return statement

Answer (score 2):

To perform a redirect from a *non-MVC* page to an MVC controller action your best bet is to use a library like [UrlRewriting.net](http://urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html) or similar which uses an HttpModule to process each request and dispatch it to a specific location.

*Example*: Redirect requests for '/faq.asp' to '/faq':

```
<add name="faq.asp" virtualUrl="^~/faq.asp([\?#].*)?$"
            destinationUrl="~/faq"
            redirect="Application"
            redirectMode="Permanent"
            ignoreCase="true" />
```

When you add the HttpModule that powers UrlRewriting.Net to your Web.config, make sure you define it **before** the UrlRoutingModule which is defined by ASP.NET automatically. Otherwise, ASP.NET will attempt to handle your request by mapping it to a a file or controller and you may experience some unexpected problems as a result.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"/>
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</modules>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just [blogged](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/aspnet-mvc-issuing-multiple-301-redirects) about a simple solution that uses ASP.NET MVC and an XML file to store the 301 redirect mappings.

However, as per Nathan Taylor's answer, if you need to do Regex based mapping, I would suggest using UrlRewriting.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Implement custom ActionResult. Example: http://www.stum.de/2008/10/22/permanentredirectresult/