# Handling/Filtering bad/broken routes/links - Redirect to existing known route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-redirect

I have the following route:

```
http://somehost/Project/Page/5/Contactgfmsdiojfdui9m
```

I want that to be permanently redirected to:

```
http://somehost/Project/Page/5/Contact
```

How i can accomplish filtering bad routes that i don't want to support?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.Net MVC 301 Redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967542/asp-net-mvc-301-redirects)

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

### Url Rewrite ([Documentation](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ProjectPageContent_Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^/Project/Page/(\d+)/Content.*" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/Project/Page/{R:1}/Content" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

### `RedirectPermanent` from Controller

**RedirectController.cs**

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ProjectPageContent(Int32 id)
    {
        return RedirectPermanent(String.Format("/Project/Page/{0}/Content", id));
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProjectPageContent_Redirect",
    url: "/Project/Page/{id}/Contact{*extra}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "ProjectPageContent" }
);
```